CORS error while using type="module" even with same origin?
my folder structure looks like this :
D:/examplefolder/index.html
and
D:/examplefolder/js1.js
code for index.html is:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="module" src="./js1.js"></script>

</body>
</html>

code for js1.js:
console.log('hello');

I am new to js, but from whatever i know, CORS error is generated if I try to access resource from different origin. So, why am i getting cors error when opening index.js using double click although they seem to have same origin??
Am I being wrong when i say they are at same origin?
I found similar question on stack overflow, but I was unable to understand it. Please Help ;(

Browsers do not trust your local file system. That stems from the possibility that you might install rogue software that instructs you to point your browser at an HTML file it installs, and that HTML file could do bad things.

When mentioning getting an error, please always post the actual, complete error message you're getting, using copy and paste. Just saying you're getting a "CORS error" is too vague. But from the sound of it, you're opening the HTML file from the file system (so the URL shown is file://something). Use HTTP instead. Most IDEs offer a way to do this, or of course you can run a local web server process.
